# Customizing table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

Could someone please give me a hint on how the virtual chapter is inserted ine the table of contents in the example below? I've tried to use `\addcontentsline` before this virtual chapter, but this splits sections of chapter 1 in the table of contents.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\addtocontents` instead of `\addcontentsline`.  The former is generic, the latter is used only to add "normal" entries.

Comment: Thank you, @Boris! I've used the line `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect \contentsline {chapter}{Randomized algorithms}{\pageref{page:randalgs}}{} }`